# Backup and Migrate module - no option to back up files?

Tags: backups

In Drupal's Backup and Migrate module (/admin/config/system/backup_migrate), the only option for "Backup from" is "Default Database". In tutorials, that drop-down seemingly should also have "Public Files Directory".

I'm a new Drupal user - is there something simple I'm missing here?

Comment: If you are hosting the site on Linux, you should give Drush a try.. With Drush you can create a DB and files backup in a single file right from the command line.

Comment: We unfortunately don't have access to the server

Answer (score 1):

There was a module which did this earlier, [Backup Migrate Files](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate_files), but it got obsolete and the code is not merged with Backup Migrate module, and is available with version 7.x-3.0
Make sure you use the latest version of the module.